# "basename: missing operand" on su command

Tags: linux, root, centos5

I've added superuser `sroot` with the following command.

```
useradd -o -r -c "service root" -g 0 -u 0 -m -d /root -s /bin/bash sroot
```

When I try to switch to that user I get the following:

```
[admin@machine ~]$ su - sroot
Password:
TERM=[xterm-r6]?
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

`whoami` shows that I'm `root` now but commands that requires root access still cannot be executed.
When I login under usual `root` everything works fine.

```
[admin@machine ~]$ uname -a
Linux <myhostname> 2.6.18-194.el5PAE #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 15:37:44 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Souns like it's something in your `.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tested with non-standard linux commands, but with scripts added with installed rpm. Those commands check `$LOGNAME` variable and require to be `root` only, not `sroot`.
Thanks @thatotherguy for your comment, which directed me to the right path to search.